# How should I write this: "Hello, Gloom!" he greets. or "Hello, Gloom!" He greets

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis, capitalization

I am writing a poem in which I personalize Perfection and Gloom.

I am confused on whether I should capitalize **he** or leave it uncapitalized as it's one sentence.

It confuses me because I also want to draw people's attention to the fact that Perfection is a person in my poem.

Comment: Hello, can you provide an example sentence where this word will appear. I saw your question title, but just for clarity is that the full sentence? and if so can you include it in your question body. - Also who is 'he' in the poem?

Comment: Perfection is personified--I get that.  You might want to consider that the only time "he" and "him" are capitalized in Am/Br writing is when referring to God.  However, you're the poet.  You have poetic license.

Comment: If it's one sentence you should definitely leave 'he' uncapitalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hello, Gloom!" he greets. Plain and simple. You would only capitalize "he" for intentional stylistic effect.

"Hi, how are you?" he asks. Always like this.

Answer (score -1):

You should write "Hello, Gloom!" He Greets. An even better way to write the sentence is ("Hello, Gloom," he greets.)